# Butter Knife- Getting null pointer when in offline but working when online

Tags: android, butterknife

I am using [Butter Knife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/) to bind view's in my app Fragment, but I am getting null point exception when the app has no internet connection but working fine when in online. Don't know why it's happening like this.. Can any one have any idea on it let me know. Thanks in advance..

This is the way I am using it in my code..

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    @BindView(R.id.myTextView)
    TextView myTextView;

    public MyFragment() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Home");

        getInfo();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_about_us, container, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

        return view;
    }

    private void getInfo () {
        if(isOnline(getActivity())) {
        // Do some thing

        myTextView.setText("Hi");

        } else {
        // do some thing

        myTextView.setText("Hello");

        }
    }

}
```

Log:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
                                                                                at butterknife.internal.Utils.findRequiredView(Utils.java:87)
                                                                                at butterknife.internal.Utils.findRequiredViewAsType(Utils.java:104)
```

Comment: `onCreate` is called before `onCreateView` so call your `getInfo()` method in `onCreateView` just after Binding the views

Comment: but it is working fine when in online no?

Comment: Here I want to load the data only once if net is available that is why I am calling it in `onCreate`.. otherwise  it loads every time if I called it in `onCreateView`

Comment: It working fine because it `isOnline` takes some time to execute while at that time view are binded thats why its working `isOnline` method

Comment: onCreateView is also called once only

Comment: @BurhanuddinRashid No here when I use to call that `getInfo()` in `onCreateView` it was calling every time when I moving between tabs..

Comment: you need to call `setoffscreenpagelimit()`...on the viewpager to prevent the fragment's view to be recreated...

Comment: hey Thanks it's working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `getInfo()` from `onCreate()`, but butterknife performs the binding just in `onCreateView()` which is called by the system **after** `onCreate()`. So `myTextView` is not initialized, when you access it in `getInfo()`.

Move `getInfo()` into onCreateView() after `Butterknife.bind()` and it should work fine.

Answer (score 3):

From [Documentation](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/)

NON-ACTIVITY BINDING

You can also perform binding on arbitrary objects by supplying your own view root.

```
public class FancyFragment extends Fragment {
  @BindView(R.id.button1) Button button1;
  @BindView(R.id.button2) Button button2;

  @Override public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fancy_fragment, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    // TODO Use fields...
    return view;
  }
}
```

You are calling `getInfo();` in `onCreate()` which in fragment lifecycle called before than `onCreateView()`

**Fragment Lifecycle**

[image]

so your `myTextView.setText("Hello");` returns null view

Regarding working in onLine mode :

```
if(isOnline(getActivity()))
```

this method will consume some time, meanwhile the view gets created in your `fragment` and also `ButterKnife.bind(this, view);` gets executed.

**EDIT**

use `setOffscreenPageLimit()` in your viewpager to avoid the fragment's being recreated each time.

```
mViewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
```

Comment: Hello! welcome to stackOverflow! if the answer helps mark it as correct by clicking the tick sign next to the answer!!